# Android ListView not loading values from SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

I am trying to load values from a database into a listview, but the listview doesn't seem to be showing the data. I first have a comment class which is in charge of getters and setters for the columns in the db.

```
package com.example.sqlite;

public class Comment {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private float itemPrice;

    public long getId( ) {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId( long id ) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public float getItemPrice() {
        return itemPrice;
    }
    public void setItemPrice(float price) {
        this.itemPrice = price;
    }

    public String getName( ) {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName( String comment ) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    // Will be used by the ArrayAdapter in the ListView.
    @Override
    public String toString( ) {
        return name;
    }
}
```

I load the values into the db with a onClick command. The issue seems to be with this line here `Comment comment = cursorToComment(cursor);` where comment is having null values instead of the values from the db. If I try doing cursor.getString(0-2) then the actual values from the db are being printed to the console. I am not sure what exactly is happening. I don't get any errors either. I have found the source of the problem, I think, but am not sure how to solve it. THe full CommentsDataSource class is listed below so you can have some context to how the list of comments is implemented.

```
package com.example.sqlite;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class CommentsDataSource {

    // Database fields
    //Used toe xecute commands on db.
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    //Opening up the mysqlhelper which is in charge of opening up connection and maintaining
    private MySQLiteHelper dbHelper;
    //Holds all the values from the database
    private String[] allColumnsItems = { MySQLiteHelper.id, MySQLiteHelper.ITEMS_COLUMN_NAME,
            MySQLiteHelper.ITEMS_PRICE };

    //Creating the default constructor
    public CommentsDataSource(Context context) {
        //Give context to the class that manages the connection
        dbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(context);
    }

    //Opening up the connction to the db
    public void open() throws SQLException {
        //Open the db for reading and writing
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase(); //getWritableDatabase is what opens the connection
    }

    //Closing the database
    public void close() throws SQLException {
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    //Creating and commiting comment
    public Comment createComment(String comment, float price) {
        //Insert into comments values('')
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        //Load the column id and value into ContentValues
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.ITEMS_COLUMN_NAME, comment);
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.ITEMS_PRICE, price);
        //Now insert into table
        long insertID = database.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_ITEMS, null, values);
        if(insertID == -1) {
            System.out.println("JSDLFJLSJDFL");
        }
        //Create a cursor to keep track of results. When creating cursors they equal database.query
        Cursor cursor =  database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_ITEMS, allColumnsItems, MySQLiteHelper.id + " = " + insertID, null, null, null, null);
        //Move cursor tot he front
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        //Return the comment which is added to listview
        return cursorToComment(cursor);
    }


    public List<Comment> getAllComments() {
        //Select * from comments
        List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<Comment>();
        //Fetching the results of query into cursor
        Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_ITEMS, allColumnsItems, null, null, null, null, null);
        //Move to front of cursor
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        //Iterate through cursor
        while(!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            Comment comment = cursorToComment(cursor);
            //Add results to arraylist
            System.out.println(comment);
            comments.add(comment);
            System.out.println(cursor.getString(2));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        System.out.println(comments);
        return comments;
    }

    public Comment cursorToComment(Cursor cursor) {
        Comment comment = new Comment();
        comment.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
        comment.setName(cursor.getString(1));
        comment.setItemPrice(cursor.getFloat(2));
        return comment;
    }

}
```

EDIT: More information about the database. Its named menu and has one table within it called items. THis table has three attributes id, title, price.

```
package com.example.sqlite;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    //Creating the items table
    public  static final String TABLE_ITEMS = "items";
    public static final String id = "_id";
    public  static final String ITEMS_COLUMN_NAME = "name";
    public  static final String ITEMS_PRICE = "price";



    private static final String DATABASE_NAME  = "menu";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION  = 1;

    // create table comments(
    //   _id integer primary key autoincrement,
    //   comment text not null );
    private static final String TABLE_CREATE_ITEMS = "create table "
            + TABLE_ITEMS + "(  " + id  + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
            +ITEMS_COLUMN_NAME + " text, "
            + ITEMS_PRICE + " real not null );";

    public MySQLiteHelper( Context context ) {
        super( context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION );
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate( SQLiteDatabase database ) {
        //Create the items table
        database.execSQL( TABLE_CREATE_ITEMS );
        //Create the combos table
        //database.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE_COMBO);
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade( SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion ) {

    }

}
```

Comment: Is there any error? see LogCat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believ that the issue is that the **setName** setter is incorrect (you set the name using name which is null, when you should be using **comment** which is the variable passed to the setter).

Using :-

```
/*
public void setName( String comment ) {
    this.name = name;
}
*/


public void setName( String comment ) {
    this.name = comment; //<<<<< CHANGED to use variable passed
}
```

Using the following to test :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CommentsDataSource cds = new CommentsDataSource(this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        cds.open();
        cds.createComment("A",10.55f);
        cds.createComment("B",20.55f);
        cds.createComment("C",30.55f);

        List<Comment> comments = cds.getAllComments();
        for (Comment c: comments) {
            Log.d("COMMENTINFO","ID=" + c.getId() + " NAME = " + c.getName() + " PRICE = " + c.getItemPrice() );
        }
    }
}
```

results in :-

```
2019-12-18 15:12:28.754 I/System.out: A
2019-12-18 15:12:28.754 I/System.out: 10.55
2019-12-18 15:12:28.754 I/System.out: B
2019-12-18 15:12:28.754 I/System.out: 20.55
2019-12-18 15:12:28.754 I/System.out: C
2019-12-18 15:12:28.754 I/System.out: 30.55
2019-12-18 15:12:28.754 I/System.out: [A, B, C]
2019-12-18 15:12:28.755 D/COMMENTINFO: ID=1 NAME = A PRICE = 10.55
2019-12-18 15:12:28.755 D/COMMENTINFO: ID=2 NAME = B PRICE = 20.55
2019-12-18 15:12:28.755 D/COMMENTINFO: ID=3 NAME = C PRICE = 30.55
```

Instead of :-

```
2019-12-18 15:17:15.830 I/System.out: null
2019-12-18 15:17:15.830 I/System.out: 10.55
2019-12-18 15:17:15.830 I/System.out: null
2019-12-18 15:17:15.830 I/System.out: 20.55
2019-12-18 15:17:15.831 I/System.out: null
2019-12-18 15:17:15.831 I/System.out: 30.55
2019-12-18 15:17:15.831 I/System.out: [null, null, null]
2019-12-18 15:17:15.832 D/COMMENTINFO: ID=1 NAME = null PRICE = 10.55
2019-12-18 15:17:15.832 D/COMMENTINFO: ID=2 NAME = null PRICE = 20.55
2019-12-18 15:17:15.832 D/COMMENTINFO: ID=3 NAME = null PRICE = 30.55
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using same `open()` method before calling `getAllComments()`

But writing in database and reading in database are not same.

you have to call

```
dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
```

So you can create a method like

```
//Opening up the connction to the db
public void read() throws SQLException {
    //Open the db for reading
    database = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
}
```

Call this method before calling `getAllComments()`

Need to modify in `Comment` Model:

```
public void setName( String comment ) {
    //this.name = name;
    //Change this to 
    this.name = comment;
}
```

Otherwise you will not get `commet` it will stay `null`.